# After updating all nuget packages on MVC4 Mobile project CSS doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

When I create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application using the Mobile Application template the solution builds and runs fine with the default code (of course).  Nuget says there are many updates available for the project.  So after updating all of them (Update All button), the solution continues to build, but when running the web app, the CSS is broken and only plan HTML is displayed in the browser. Why is the CSS broken after the Nuget update?

Answer (score 4):

Looking into this I noticed that Nuget was updating the project to jQuery 2.0.2.  I also found that the max version of jQuery that jQuery Mobile [currently supports](http://api.jquerymobile.com/) is 1.9.1.  So I let Nuget update all the packages to their latest versions except the jQuery scripts (which are version 1.8.2 in the project template).  I used the Nuget Package Manager Console and manually updated jQuery to version 1.9.1 using the following command:

PM> Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1 -ProjectName

Everything built and CSS works fine.  Apparently, this version of Nuget has an issue with this particular dependency check.

Comment: I wish I had more that one +1 to give you.  Thank you!