# MVC 4 mobile 1.3.1 line 26 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error Unable to set property mobile of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

1. In Visual Studio 2012 pro, Update 2, Create MVC 4 web app project,
   select Mobile template
2. Run: it's working properly
3. Manage Nuget packages, update JQuery to 2.0.2
4. Run: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
5. In App_Start->BundleConfig.cs, change "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*" to
       "~/Scripts/jquery-2.*"
6. Run: JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 11 in
   /Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.map, SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
7. Manage Nuget packages, update ASP MVC 4
8. Run:  same error as in #6
9. Manage Nuget packages, update JQuery Mobile to 1.3.1
10. Run:  same error as in #6
11. In Views->Shared->_Layout.cshtml, moved  @ Scripts
     .Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile" ) to end of head section
12. Run: line 26 jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js, 0x800a138f - JavaScript
     runtime error Unable to set property mobile of undefined or null
     reference
13. Manage Nuget packages, update JQuery UI (Combined) to 1.10.3
14. Run:  same error as in #12
15. Manage Nuget packages, update ALL
16. Run:  same error as in #12

Has someone been naughty and not tested their latest nuget packages for compatibility?   Seems like we're in Javascript library hell...

I also tried the jQuery Migrate plugin 1.2.1, with no joy.

Where did I go wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302258/after-updating-all-nuget-packages-on-mvc4-mobile-project-css-doesnt-work might be jQuery 2.0 problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I undid #11, putting the jquerymobile reference back into the body and then removed the two map files from the Scripts folder.

This fixed the problem. :)

Think Snow...